# Trying to loop through items in a hash and return only certain ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

I have the following function that decodes a URL into a hash comprised of different pieces of the URL. For example, after the first line where I assign `hash`, I receive this output:

```
>> CGI.parse(URI.parse("http://google.com/?foo=bar&baz=hello").query)
=> {"foo"=>["bar"], "baz"=>["hello"]}
```

In this function, I'm trying to pull values if the key is "p" or "q". I essentially want to filter the hash into only the keys and values I want.

My goal is to only show the keywords someone searches for such as `brick` or `cement`.

Here's my function:

```
  def self.get_search_terms(search_url)
    hash = CGI.parse(URI.parse(URI.encode(search_url)).query) #returns a hash
    keywords = []
    hash.each do |key|
      if key["q"] != nil || 
        key["p"] != nil
        keywords << key
      end
    end
    keywords
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
def self.get_search_terms(search_url)
  hash = CGI.parse(URI.parse(URI.encode(search_url)).query)
  keywords = []
  hash.each do |key, value|
    if key == 'p' || key == 'q'
      keywords << value
    end
  end
  keywords
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to mark this one as correct since it's much cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

The more idiomatic ruby way, essentially a one liner:

```
def self.get_search_terms(search_url)
  CGI.parse(URI.parse(URI.encode(search_url)).query).values_at('q','p')
end
```

see [Hash#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)

If you want to eliminate empty params, add a reject blank to it:

```
.values_at('q','p').reject(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of 100 ways to do it!

```
def self.get_search_terms(search_url)
  myhash = CGI.parse(URI.parse(URI.encode(search_url)).query) 
  keywords = []
  ["p","q"].each do |mykey|
     if myhash.has_key?(mykey)
       keywords << myhash[mykey]
     end
  end
  keywords
end
```

Or maybe

```
def self.get_search_terms(search_url)
  myhash = CGI.parse(URI.parse(URI.encode(search_url)).query) 
  keywords = []
  mykeywords = ["p","q"]
  mykeywords.each do |mykey|
    if myhash.has_key?(mykey)
      keywords << myhash[mykey]
    end
  end
  keywords
end
```

In both versions,  it's the list of keywords you are looking for that is the initial loop.  You implicitly iterate over the hash extracted from the URI by using:

myhash.has_key?

That will iterate over my hash,  and if it contains the key,  ad the key's value to keywords.

Comment: Thanks RadBrad. I'm a bit confused about the line ['p','q'].each do |mykey|. Why are you doing a .each on ['p'] and ['q'] here?

Comment: It was just a very brief way to do it.  I'll update post to show another version,  making it clear , hopefully